# After a site rebuild on first login the session is destroyed after redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I am currently getting an issue after an ASP.NET MVC 4 site is rebuilt that I was not getting previously.

We log in to a 3rd party site that redirects to our site with an authentication payload. A Session_Start is hit and the payload is successfully processed and a Session variable with the users details is created. We then do a RedirectToAction to send the user to another page.

On the first login after the site has been rebuilt Session_Start is hit again and a new Session is being created on the Redirect where previously it was not doing this. As our site checks for and treats an invalid session as being incorrect it sends the user back to the 3rd party site to log in again. When next they login they do not get this issue.

This looks to be happening when the site recycles as well. It only occurs for the very first user that logins to the site after its been rebuilt.

This only began happening in the last 2 weeks and I have reviewed any changes that went into the site in that time but could not find an obvious cause of the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have run into similar problems... What I could figure out was it seems like IIS "rebuilds" the code, on teh first access after a new build/upload. So the first access, actually creates a rebuild/compile in IIS... To solve it.. I just access the site once after I upload... that sets the rebuild in action.. and consecutive visits are fine.

Comment: If you want to research this further, this is probably more an IIS thing than an issue with your project...